# Matplotlib animation repeating even whit repeat set to False

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I'm trying to create an animation with `matplotlib`.
I have the following code:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation as ani
import ffmpeg

xValues = np.empty((4, 100))              # Initialize the vectors
yValues = np.empty((4, 100))

for i in np.arange(100):                    # Populate the vectors
    xValues[:,i] = np.random.random(4)
    yValues[:,i] = np.random.random(4)

k = 0                                      # Initialisation of k
myFig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,5))
p, = ax.plot([],[])

def animFunc(j):                           # Animation function
    global k, p
    j = int(j)
    p.remove()
    p, = ax.plot(xValues[:,k],yValues[:,k])
    p.set_data(xValues[:,k],yValues[:,k])
    k += 1
    return p,

animator = ani.FuncAnimation(myFig, animFunc, interval=1, blit=True, repeat=False, frames=100)
animator.save('my_video.mp4', writer='ffmpeg', fps=50, bitrate=1000)
```

I am basically plotting two vectors `xValues,yValues` which have size 100 along axis 1.

When I run the code, the video is created, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\...\my_code.py", line 30, in <module>
    animator.save('my_video.mp4', writer='ffmpeg', fps=50, bitrate=1000)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1152, in save
    anim._draw_next_frame(d, blit=False)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1192, in _draw_next_frame
    self._draw_frame(framedata)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1755, in _draw_frame
    self._drawn_artists = self._func(framedata, *self._args)
  File "C:\...\...\my_code.py", line 24, in animFunc
    p, = ax.plot(xValues[:,k],yValues[:,k])
IndexError: index 100 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 100
```

Seemingly, the function is trying to repeat the animation after the last frame (then the repetition starts at the index `k = 100`, which is too large for `xValues, yValues`). But why does it do so? I have set `repeat=False` in the declaration.

Also, how would you tune the `bitrate` parameter? Is 1000 a good value?

---

**EDIT 1:** JohanC's solution works fine, I tried to implement a dummy InitFunction (the `ax` objects are initialised once, out of any function) and to substitute `k` with `j` and now there's no additional calls to the animation!

Comment: If you don't provide an init function, `animFunc` will be called instead. That makes it will be called 101 times, leading to the crash at the last call. A solution could be to provide a dummy init function that doesn't increase `k`. Note that in general, for speed and memory use considerations, `p.remove()` and `p, = ax.plot(..)` shouldn't be called inside the animation function (only `p.set_data(...)` would be needed).  For the `bitrate`, you need to experiment. It should be high enough to get enough quality, and low enough to avoid files growing too large.

Comment: Also note that instead of the global variable `k`, it's recommended to just use the animation parameter (`j` in this case) instead. That way you would avoid the problem altogether.  In general, it's recommended to reduce the use of `global` as much as possible.

Comment: Thank you for your useful insights, removing the global ```k``` variable was the key!+

Comment: @JohanC just another question, if I remove the ```global``` declarations inside the animation and init functions, then I get an error like "local variabile xyz referenced before assignment", where xyz is instead one of the global variables... why aren't they identified correctly?

Answer (score 1):

When a global variable is only read inside a function, the `global` declaration is not needed.  If, however, you call `p, = ax.plot(...)` inside the function with a global declaration, a local variable with the same name is created. This will cause the "referenced before assignment" error.

Calling `p, = ax.plot(...)` inside the update function isn't recommended, as that slows down the execution.

In your case, you seem to want to draw 4 curves simultaneously, while most `funcAnimation` examples only draw 1 curve.  With 4 curves, `ax.plot` returns, well, 4 curves. In the simple case, `ax.plot` returns a **list** with one curve, and often the unintuitive comma notation is used to extract the first (and only) element of that list.  With 4 curves, you do want to receive the full list (therefore, no comma is used).

The setup will need 4 dummy curves, which you could create via a 1-by-4 array of `nan` values. To avoid that the animation keeps moving the limits around, usually some fixed limits are set from the start.

Here is some example code:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation as ani

xValues = np.empty((4, 100))  # Initialize the vectors
yValues = np.empty((4, 100))

for i in np.arange(100):  # Populate the vectors
    xValues[:, i] = np.random.random(4)
    yValues[:, i] = np.random.random(4)

myFig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
empty_values = np.empty((1, 4))
empty_values[:] = np.nan
lines = ax.plot(empty_values, empty_values)
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)

def initFunc():
    return lines

def animFunc(j):  # Animation function
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        line.set_data(xValues[i, :j], yValues[i, :j])
    return lines

animator = ani.FuncAnimation(myFig, animFunc, init_func=initFunc, interval=1, blit=True, repeat=False, frames=100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Johan, But in your example the saved GIF is still repeating despite the repeat=False parameter (tried both pillow and imagemagick writers).

Comment: Well, this question was about showing an animation on screen. When saving, you can use `animator.save(filename, extra_args=....)` where `extra_args` are parameters sent to the program that is saving. This depends on which environment you are using, and how matplotlib is configured there.   See also [Animation.save](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.Animation.html#matplotlib.animation.Animation.save) in matplotlib's docs.

Comment: If you have `ffmpeg` installed, `anim.save(filename, extra_args=['-loop','1'])` might work for you.  Here `1` means loop 1 time. The default is `0` to loop forever.

Comment: Yep, I found the trick with extra_args=['-loop','1'] as well, but the repeat=False in FuncAnimation seems to have no effect at all which seems odd...

Comment: `repeat=False` in `FuncAnimation` only has effect on the interactive display of the animation, not on the saved file.  Matplotlib saving happens via external programs, which can be configured.  Those external programs don't have a fixed set of parameters. Each program has its own (huge) set of parameters.  These influence file size, animation quality and much more.

Comment: Now I get it, thanks!